# Sorting lua lists

Tags: list, sorting, lua

I have a list in lua that looks something like this:

```
list = {{1, 25, 31, 50, 5, 6}, {3, 22, 14, 82, 14, 1}, {2, 13, 40, 67, 92, 12},}
```

I want to be able to sort it by the first number in each set of braces, so it will become this:

```
list = {{1, 25, 31, 50, 5, 6}, {2, 13, 40, 67, 92, 12}, {3, 22, 14, 82, 14, 1}}
```

I have tried `table.sort()` but that doesn't seem to work.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: `table.sort(list, function(a, b) return a[1] < b[1] end)`

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table.sort(list, function(a, b) return a[1] < b[1] end)
```

The second argument to `table.sort` is a sorting function. So in this case we look into the first item in `a` and `b` and use that to compare.